# JQuery Selectors: How to select item with class and id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to select div with class(.multi-steps-content section) inside div with id(#box-1).  I want to count number of section using combination of id and class, but on this way i can't to get valid number of section, because i don't know how to combination id with class.

This is my code:

```js
var $divID = $('div.multi-steps-wrapper').attr('id');

var $length = $(" " + $divID + " .multi-steps-content section").length;
console.log($length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-multi-steps">
  <div id="box-1" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-steps-content">
      <form action="" id="form-property">

        <section>1</section>
        <section>2</section>
        <section>3</section>

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--.multi-steps-content-->
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>

<div id="box-2" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-steps-content">
    <form action="" id="form-property">

      <section>1</section>
      <section>2</section>
      <section>3</section>

    </form>
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-content-->
</div>
<!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem more clearly?

Comment: This is the problem `$(" "+$divID+" .multi-steps-content section").length; ` should be `$("#"+$divID+" .multi-steps-content section").length; `

Comment: But why do you want to do it with id and class?

Comment: I want to select section in class with parent #box-1.
For example 
var $length = $("#box-1 .multi-step-content section").length

But i have #box-2, #box-3, #box-4 ...

Comment: Do all the boxes have the class `multi-steps-wrapper` added to them? or how are you otherwise identifying which box you're currently trying to target? We need a bit more context.

Comment: Yes, all boxes have multi step wrapper

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen 
With this i get only length of section from #box-1. For my code I need length of section in all boxes.

Comment: @d.s then you should not use id, look at the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```js
$('div.multi-steps-content').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest(".multi-steps-wrapper").attr("id"), $(this).find("section").length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-multi-steps">
  <div id="box-1" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-steps-content">
      <form action="" id="form-property">

        <section>1</section>
        <section>2</section>
        <section>3</section>

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--.multi-steps-content-->
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>

<div id="box-2" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-steps-content">
    <form action="" id="form-property">

      <section>1</section>
      <section>2</section>
      <section>3</section>

    </form>
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-content-->
</div>
<!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>
```

Lookup:

```js
const content = {}
$('div.multi-steps-content').each(function() {
  content[$(this).closest(".multi-steps-wrapper").attr("id")] = $(this).find("section").length
})
console.log("Step 1 has",content["box-1"],"steps")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-multi-steps">
  <div id="box-1" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-steps-content">
      <form action="" id="form-property">

        <section>1</section>
        <section>2</section>
        <section>3</section>

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--.multi-steps-content-->
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>

<div id="box-2" class="multi-steps-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-steps-content">
    <form action="" id="form-property">

      <section>1</section>
      <section>2</section>
      <section>3</section>

    </form>
  </div>
  <!--.multi-steps-content-->
</div>
<!--.multi-steps-wrapper-->
</div>
```